# C# outlook search address antry by ID, Username or Alias

Tags: c#, get, outlook, connect

Hi Guys I need an solution to find an contact of my GlobalAddressList by ID, Username or Alias.

This is my try, but only for an search by name:

```
AddressList gal = appl.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
AddressEntry entry = gal.AddressEntries["xxxx"];
ExchangeUser ae = entry.GetExchangeUser();
```

Comment: Noboby know an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Call Namespace.CreateRecipient, Recipient.Resolve, tnen use Recipient.AddressEntry.

What Id do you mean? EntryID (use Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID) or some other id, such as SMTP address or NT account name?